# Separating alternatives using slash/stroke where the only difference is the length

Tags: slash

I'm wondering about the usage of slash/stroke as a way of separating alternatives (perhaps it, in this sense, could be called a abbreviation of "or"?). If the alternatives are similar, but the second one is longer, then how would I write this as short as possible, with the smallest possible risk for confusion? Let me give you an example:

I have a card reader where you can insert a Memory Stick or a Memory Stick Pro. If I label the card reader with "MS/Pro", it could most certainly be interpreted as "either MS or Pro". Still, I want the label to be as short as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a slight risk involved using a slash.  While "or" is implicitly added while reading a sentence using slash, slash is used often enough in other contexts that it might require a reader to stop and repeat in order to get the proper meaning, which, if your priority is clarity, you should always avoid.  However in order to reduce space, I can also see the necessity.

I would recommend only that if you were to use a slash in this instance, I would write "MS/MS Pro", since it isn't "MS" or "Pro" but "MS" or "MS Pro" as your two options.  I see your dilemma, though surely you can have a label which holds "MS/MS Pro".

Comment: Yes, well I guess you're right. By the way, I don't really have a card reader. I intended to write "Let's say I have ..." but I managed to remove that part, while reorganizing the text before posting.

Comment: Well the solution still fits doesn't it?  You need to write Memory Stick or Memory Stick Pro in a small space.  Does MS/MS Pro do fine then?

Comment: Yes, and now I have enough rep to upvote your answer. ^^ But say if I want to write a text like "Visual Studio 2008/Visual Studio 2010". Then it would be more motivated to be able to do something like "Visual Studio 2008/2010". But, as you say, I guess the slash is too ambiguous to eliminate the risk for confusion and misinterpretation.

Comment: Good point.  In that case, I think it's clear because by the time you read "Visual Studio", you're expecting a year, so separating years with slashes is kind of intuitive.  I think you could only get away with that if it's a date, number, version (something countable in other words).  Thanks for the upvote btw.  :)

Comment: If you want to be even shorter - at the expense of being slightly less clear - you could even have *MS (/Pro)*

Comment: or even "Visual Studio 2008/10"

Answer (score 1):

The conventional way to do this is with brackets instead of a slash:

> Memory Stick (Pro)

However, this might not be the best choice in this case, since brackets can also be used for other things with names. On the label, Neil's *MS / MS Pro* would be excellent. In a manual, you could say *Memory Stick or Memory Stick Pro* the first time, then Neil's *MS / MS Pro* afterwards, or just *the stick*, since people will now know what you are referring to.

If only all writers of manuals and computer technicians considered the interpretation of their labels and terms so diligently!